# How to preview estimated file size in Vegas Pro?

Tags: windows-10, video-editing, sony-vegas

There are certain features advertised on Vegas Movie Studio that Vegas Pro doesn't have, and vice-versa.  Vegas Pro doesn't advertise the "Estimated file size" preview text, which is important to me and available on VMS.

Is there a way to see the estimated file size in Vegas Pro?

Comment: Where in the Vegas UI does this typically show up? Are you just missing a setting perhaps? I'd also guess that because file size varies greatly based on a wide range of preferences that are not available in the basic version, it makes sense to put it in the simpler version, but not in the more complex and more capable full version.

Comment: I see, @music2myear. It appears on the bottom of the render options in Vegas Movie Studio. Please refer to this screenshot: bit.ly/2CMOQeE